# java switch statement mechanism

Tags: java, switch-statement

In the below code when i comment the breaks,when i write a case(say "start") it will print all the cases output below,means all the three lines are printed,when i write "stop" it prints two output "Mechine stopped" and "No command given",why do i need to give break statement as  the compiler searches for the cases,if matches then print the related output.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class App{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String text = input.nextLine();
    switch(text){
        case "start":
        System.out.println("Mechine Started");
        break;
        case "stop":
        System.out.println("Mechine stopped");
        break;
        default:
        System.out.println("No command given");


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Side note, in general you will want to further indent the code under each case, as if they were surrounded by curly braces

Answer (score 6):

> why do i need to give break statement as the compiler searches for the
>   cases,if matches then print the related output.

Because that's how it's defined to work. Your program will *fall-through* the remaining case clauses unless you explicitly `break`

See the [JLS section 14.11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html) and note:

> If one of the case constants is equal to the value of the expression,
>   then we say that the case matches, and all statements after the
>   matching case label in the switch block, if any, are executed in
>   sequence.

It's similar to the switch behaviour in C, note. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Fallthrough):

> Languages derived from C, and more generally those influenced by
>   Fortran's computed GOTO, instead feature fallthrough, where control
>   moves to the matching case, and then execution continues ("falls
>   through") to the statements associated with the next case in the
>   source text

Answer (score 1):

[Fall through](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

> Another point of interest is the break statement. Each break statement terminates the enclosing switch statement. Control flow continues with the first statement following the switch block. **The break statements are necessary because without them, statements in switch blocks fall through: All statements after the matching case label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of subsequent case labels**, until a break statement is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Without using **break** in switch statement is ***fall-through logic***

switch statement did not say **"You need to include break".**

Best practice is that you should add comment **//fall-through** when you used this logic.